# Make rawdisk exclusively available to guest system?

Tags: virtualbox, vmdk

Selecting a USB stick in VirtualBox makes the USB stick available to the guest system and unavailable to the host system (in my case Windows), so that the host system can't interfere with the guest system. Is there a way to achieve the same thing with raw disks? I can make disks generated with `vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk` available to the guest system simply by adding them to the guest system's storage devices in the settings panel, but the host system still can write to them, which causes the guest system to crash most of the time. Is there a way to make a raw disk unavailable to the host system like VirtualBox does with USB sticks?

**EDIT:** In my case I want to install a Windows system to a USB stick. But since Windows rejects USB sticks as installation targets, I figured I trick Windows into installing onto a USB stick by disguising it as hard drive, which is exactly what raw VMDKs do. Though the host system starts to yell at me as soon as the guest system changes the USB stick's partition table, which does not happen, if I attach the USB stick the normal way. However attaching the USB stick the normal way makes Windows reject the USB stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using the tool [Vrtual Machine USB Boot](https://github.com/DavidBrenner3/VMUB) I got VirtualBox to install Windows to a USB drive (the guest system and with it the Windows installer thinks it's a SATA device).

This solves my initial goal described in the edit, so I'm gonna mark it as correct,